# How not to pass an if test?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have one dictionary, like the following:

```
adict = {'1': alist, '0': blist, '2': clist}
```

I want to perform some things, for all lists
in adict except the list with the key '0'.

So I have tried:

```
for key in adict:
    if key is not '0':
        do something
```

but the test doesnot work,
something is done in all cases,
including the one that key=='0'.

I cannot figure out, what is wrong, any help?

Comment: This code executes just fine for me, and goes into "do something" only for `alist` and `clist`.  Are you sure you're not loosing something in the translation to a simple example for us?

Comment: Modified code (do something as print and some dummy lists for real) works. In any case, you will want to check for value condition via `!=`or `==` paired with a continue. As @JeffL. suggests, please update question with less "edited" code that also o your system produces the error. Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`is` test for object equality, not value equality.  So you're look here if the `key` is the exact same string object as the literal `'0'` you type next, not whether the string has the same value.  You should probably test for non-equal values like

```
if key != '0':
    <do something>
```

Comment: This is correct and people should be careful with `is` and `==`, but in Python 2.7 the way he did it should evaluate the way he expects.  That is, `'0' == '0'` and `'0' is '0'` are both true.  I'm wondering if he's mixing dtypes maybe.

Comment: @JeffL. yeah, I was surprised that OP reported that this didn't work for `'0'`, so perhaps there's something even deeper going on too